# Iterator of Vector<Vector<Point> >

Tags: opencv, vector, iterator

I know these iterator questions have been asked and answered a thousand times, however when I compile the following code, I still get this error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'cv::Vector<_Tp> *'

.

```
void iterate(vector<vector<cv::Point> >& contours){
  Vector<Vector<cv::Point>>::iterator it = contours.begin();
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){
    if(contourArea(contours[i])>1000){
        it++;
    }else{
        contours.erase(it);
    }
}
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with this code. The template type of the vector for the new iterator is the same like the vector I'm getting the iterator from.

Comment: One is uppercase One is lowercase? Vector vs vector ?

Comment: Arghh! Thanks! That was it! Didn't know there was a difference in Vectors and vectors! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can not convert errors are generally very literal. Often the types used can give hints where in your code somethng is wrong.

Here we have the use of uppercase `Vector` class to define your iterator, and you are assigning a lowercase `Vector` class to it.

Note you would probably have gotten a different error if Vector was not a real class.